# Is Samsung's Media Hub only available to new customers?

Tags: samsung

Are old donkeys not allowed to eat carrots?!

Answer (score 1):

Appears to currently be US only, and only added in the latest Epic 4G update. However the marketing materials keep mentioning Galaxy S devices, rather than any specific models, so it could well roll out to the rest of the Galaxy S range in future updates, or possibly even via the on-device Samsung Apps store that most Galaxy S's have (assuming your phone company hasn't removed it).

However it's worth bearing in mind that this is a transparent attempt to lock you into Samsung for future phone and TV purchases, as once you've built up a large library of paid content on their media store, you're probably not going to want to move to hardware where you can't watch that content. If you're happy with that then ok, personally I'll stick to more hardware independant media vendors.

Comment: To be honest I was more after the free copy of Inception! - I was sure I'd seen TV ads for SGS's with Inception free in the UK...perhaps I dreamed it!

Comment: @Adrian I've seen posters on the side of buses for that around London, but assumed the film was pre-loaded onto the SD card, or something along those lines.

Comment: From some searches I've done, I got the impression that you had to have Media Hub to play the bundled Inception movie...

Answer (score 1):

No, I've had Media Hub since I was running 2.1 in August 2010 (on my Vibrant).  I'm sure you could get it from somewhere and side-load it.

Comment: What's your zip code (if you don't mind sharing)?  I've tried numerous zip codes and it keeps telling me that I'm not in a supported location.

Comment: It was 60661 when I got the phone.